# Are there differences between the paystubs of W2 and paystubs of 1099?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Are there differences between the paystubs or earning statements of W2 and paystubs of 1099?

Can one tell if a paystub or earning statement belongs to W2 employment or to 1099 employment? If yes, how?

Comment: Are Social Security and Medicare taxes withheld?

Comment: Could you give me some examples of the paystubs of w2 employment and of 1099 employment? So I can see the difference?

Comment: 1099 - gross pay and net pay are same. No withholdings. W2 - net pay is gross pay - sum of withholdings.

Answer (score 5):

A W-2 employee is an employee. Their paycheck will have withholding for Federal taxes, state taxes, Social Security and Medicare. The employee may also have withholding for health insurance, Dental insurance, Vision Insurance. There may also be withholding for 401K. At the end of January they will receive 1 W-2 for the previous year.

If a person isn't an employee they are a self-employed individual. They will bill a company for their services. They will not have anything withheld for taxes, Social Security or Medicare. They will not receive benefits such as insurance or 401K.

A big clue is on day one:

- A employee will submit a W-4 for the federal and state taxes. This directs the employer regarding instructions for calculating withholding. They will get a W-2 in January.
- a contractor will fill out a W-9 form. And then at the end of January get 1099.

Comment: Thanks.  If only have access to paystubs (no other information such as tax forms), is it correct that to tell whether the employment is w2 or 1099 based,  is to see whether the paystubs have withheld for taxes, Social Security or Medicare?

Comment: Each pay stub will specify the withholding. If those items (taxes, social security, medicare) are listed then you are an employee.